# BCP use produces incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am new to the bcp tool. Below is sample code copied from the Microsoft site which I adapted for our server.  This is for SQL server.
It works fine until the last line, which is the bcp call.
Here it get the error message

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '-'."

Would this be some kind of issue where bcp is not installed on our server?

### Thanks

```
USE CH_Reports;
GO
if OBJECT_ID('myTestCharData','Table') is not null
drop table myTestCharData

CREATE TABLE myTestCharData (
   Col1 smallint,
   Col2 nvarchar(50),
   Col3 nvarchar(50)
   ); 

INSERT INTO myTestCharData(Col1,Col2,Col3)
   VALUES(1,'DataField2','DataField3');
INSERT INTO myTestCharData(Col1,Col2,Col3)
   VALUES(2,'DataField2','DataField3');
GO
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM myTestCharData

-bcp myTestCharData out C:\myTestCharData-c.Dat -c -t, -T
```

Comment: BTW, when asking about a tool that ships with a specific database, you should generally also tag that question for the database it comes with.

Comment: You might also link to the Microsoft page you were trying to copy from.

Comment: Presuming that the SQL is saved to a file called `myTestCharData` and you are running the bcp executable on a command line? Not inline within the script?

Comment: My guess would be it's the dash in the filename (`C:\myTestCharData-c.Dat`) and that you need to include the filename in a string